# how to customize an android library

Tags: android, kotlin, customization

how can I change and customize an android library which has only-read status?

I have implemented the library by adding that in my 'gradle';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to include the java files locally in your project rather than importing through gradle.

IE -

src/main/java/com/example/project -

- package1
- package2
- libraries/OSSLib/

You can either import all class files into this, or only the relevant ones you want to modify while still importing through gradle. If you do the second, be wary of imports.

**VERIFY THAT THE OSS LICENSE ALLOWS YOU TO DO THIS.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on the Library separately.

1. Open your library as a project and make changes.
2. Build. aar file of the library
3. Add library in your app project's gradle

Comment: how can I make a change in the library, the problem is some classes are read-only. how can I change them to writable

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible options.

- play with inheritance (for example, if you need change a way of drawing override `onDraw()` method)
- download library source code and add as other module (other project etc.). Then you can fully modify the whole code, but it's up to you to maintain library etc.
- use reflection to modify some things (like private params) at runtime etc.

I think that last option can be acceptable only in some cases - it's really depends what you are going to achieve.